# How to access gradle parameter in Java code

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I have some experience with java and I am new to gradle and I joined a project in which I have to modify the gradle file.

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10',
                'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.53.0'
}

test {
    useTestNG()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

I then run my test suite using the following command from the mac terminal
`./build test`

I want to pass a parameter named `environment`
Based on this value of this parameter, I need to configure my urls and run tests for that environment. Something like `./build test environment=dev` or `./build test environment=qa`

And in my java code I would do something like this

```
if(env == 'dev') {
    url = "my dev url";
    user = "my dev user name"
} else if(env == 'qa') {
    url = "my qa url";
    user = "my qa user name"
}
```

How can I pass this parameter in the terminal ? 
A small snippet of how I can use this parameter in my code would be of great help (my java code does not have a main method).

Note: I have already used a property file and achieved this behaviour, but my team does not want to make changes in code to set the environment. So I had to discard those changes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From command line to gradle you can use system properties or project properties. It will be either:

```
./gradlew test -Denv=dev
```

or

```
./gradle test -Penv=dev
```

The properties above can be now read in a `build.gradle`, you need to pass them to tests as well, it must be done with system properties so:

```
test {
    systemProperty 'env', System.properties['env'] ?: 'dev'
}
```

for system properties from command line or:

```
test {
    systemProperty 'env', project.hasProperty('env') ? project.env : 'dev'
}
```

In test classes use just:

```
System.getProperty("env")
```

to get the value you need.

Comment: I have such line line in my build script `run { systemProperty 'version', server_version }` and when I try to reach variable in java code by `System.getProperty("version)` I'm getting null. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @KarolKulbaka `run` task is of task `JavaExec` and it has `systemProperties` method defined: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:systemProperties.

Comment: I know this, but I still get a zero when I try to get my property

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: I have property `server_version` in gradle.properties and run section in build.gradle as described before. I've created empty project witch only print property added like above and it's still null. I'm using kotlin and application gradle plugins.

Comment: I've created a test in empty project and add system property same way in test section and it's working.

Comment: I found problem. It was the way of launch project. I was running project by javac instead of gradlew run